# How to use AG plugin to search a word inside a git repo?

Tags: key-bindings, search

I want to enable [vim-ag](https://github.com/rking/ag.vim) to search a word inside specific directory.

Currently I have the following mapping in my `vimrc`:

```
noremap <leader>a  :Ag! <C-r>=expand('<cword>')<CR><CR>
```

which searchs the `cword` in the current directory.

I want to expand it a bit so that I would be able to search in another directory as well.

I'm not sure if I can use `noremap` to get additional input (the target directory). If this is possible - then that would be best (i.e. press `<leader>a` -> add somehow the target directory -> Ag will search the `cword` in target directory)

If not - I want to config Ag manually - with another binding, to look in my git repo head directory - something like:

```
noremap <leader>a  :Ag! <C-r>=expand('<cword>') <GIT REPO DIR><CR><CR>
```

1. would that work (I'm not sure if the expand operator breaks things or not
2. how do I get the git repo dir?

Comment: 1. It's "register", not "buffer". 2. You appear to be asking two different things: how to use the visually highlighted text in a command and how to make your plugin search in the working directory. Those are separate problems that you should ask about in separate questions.

Comment: Thanks for the coment - I'll rephrase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand-side of your mapping is a macro: a collection of keystroke that Vim performs for you. This means that, with the cursor on `foo`, your mapping "types" the following in the command-line:

```
Ag! foo
```

and immediately presses `<CR>`, executing the command.

If you want a chance to provide a directory, you can simply:

- add a space after the first `<CR>`,
- and remove the second `<CR>`, like this:

  nnoremap a :Ag! =expand('')

It will leave you there:

```
:Ag! foo
         ^
```

ready to type your directory. If you don't want to specify a directory, just press `<CR>`.

That said, the plugin seems to have an option https://github.com/rking/ag.vim#configuration, that might help with your underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose you to make sure the current working directory is the directory of the git root.

To achieve that automatically you could use the [vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `input()` to request input. Something like `:nnoremap <leader>a :Ag! stuff <C-r>=input('directory')<CR><CR>`
2. If you’re already using fugitive, it provides `FugitiveGitDir()`; otherwise, something like `systemlist('git rev-parse --git-dir')[0]`, I think.

Comment: I do use fugitive! I'll check it, thanks